# Approximating $\frac{x-y}{w-z}$ in terms of $\frac{x}{w}$ and $\frac{y}{z}$

Tags: approximation, fractions

I have the expression $\frac{x-y}{w-z}$ and I would like to approximate it in two fractions, $x/w$ and $y/z$. Ideally a linear combination of $x/w$ and $y/z$ and their powers. If that is not possible, a non-linear expression will also do.

Comment: It was already pointed out in response to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4069226/42969 that $\frac{x-y}{w-z}$ can take arbitrary values, without $x/w$ or $y/z$ changing. If you want to *approximate* the expression now then you have to specify a range for those variables where the approximation should hold.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  We can multiply numerator and denominator of $\frac xw$ by $k$ without changing the value of the fraction.  As $k\to\infty$, $\frac{kx-y}{kw-z}\to\frac xw$, but as $k\to0$, $\frac{kx-y}{kw-z}\to\frac yz$.  That is, $\frac{kx-y}{kw-z}\to\frac xw$ can't be approximated as a fuction of $\frac wx$ and $\frac yz$.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can. Suppose $y = z = 1$. Then you want to approximate
$$
A = \frac{x-1}{w-1}
$$
using $B = x/w$ and the number $1$. But $A$ can be any value between $1$ and $B$.